# Embeding ESRI compatible ArcGIS projection using GDAL?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, raster-conversion

Is there any way to embed ESRI compatible ArcGIS projection using GDAL -tools?

Currently I am using gdalwarp to create raster file which translate raster from WGS84 (EPSG:4326) to Spherical Mercator (EPSG:3857). It also create Geotiff with tags and tfw -file.

`gdalwarp -q -overwrite -s_srs '+init=epsg:4326' -t_srs '+init=epsg:3857' -r bilinear -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -co TFW=YES...`

It still not open correctly when opening in ESRI ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 but complining missing projection. Is it possible to create raster file which open directly and correctly in ArcGIS environment and can be produced by using GDAL tools?

Comment: Have you tried with plain geotiff without the .TFW file?

Comment: yes, it works! Also ArcGIS recognize EPSG:3857 projection when using only tfw -file without geotiff -adds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If .tfw file does not exist then ArcGIS is forced to read the georeferencing from the GeoTIFF tags and then it hopefully reads and interprets also the projection tags.

If ArcGIS can't interpret the projection correctly from the GeoTIFF tags you can create an ESRI .prj file with gdalsrsinfo http://www.gdal.org/gdalsrsinfo.html

```
gdalsrsinfo -o wkt_esri epsg:3857

PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```